# External pdf renderers

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I want to use external font to render my VF page into pdf but documentation says that it's impossible. Is there some workaround? Can we utilize some external (sales force approved) service or library?

Comment: Most likely what you want to do is possible, but its not clear to me at least what you are trying to accomplish. Could you elaborate on your requirements/objectives. Screenshots might help a lot. Why are external fonts important? What do you do with the generated PDF afterwards? What documentation exactly (link)?

Comment: external fonts are required by customer - they've provided fonts and want to see pdf with